# How to observe the states of multiple LiveData?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm

I’m trying to observe the loading state of a page. However, I make 2 API calls on my ViewModel. I want to display a progress bar until both of the items are loaded.

I have a sealed class to indicate the loading state of the data, which goes like:

```
sealed class DataState<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : DataState<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : DataState<Nothing>()
    object Loading : DataState<Nothing>()
}
```

My view model:

```
init {
    getData1()
    getData2()
}

val data1 = MutableLiveData<List<model1>>()
val data2 = MutableLiveData<List<model2>>()

private fun getData1() {
    viewModelScope.launch {

        data1.postValue(DataState.Loading)

        val result = try {
            repository.getData1().data!!
        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            data1.postValue(DataState.Error(e))
            return@launch
        }
        
        data1.postValue(DataState.Success(result))
    }
}

private fun getData2() {
    viewModelScope.launch {

        data2.postValue(DataState.Loading)

        val result = try {
            repository.getData2().data!!
        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            data2.postValue(DataState.Error(e))
            return@launch
        }

        data2.postValue(DataState.Success(result))
    }
}
```

I wanna observe a live data so that I can see that both of the states are successful. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want a [`MediatorLiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData):

```
 LiveData liveData1 = ...;
 LiveData liveData2 = ...;

 MediatorLiveData liveDataMerger = new MediatorLiveData<>();
 liveDataMerger.addSource(liveData1, value -> liveDataMerger.setValue(value));
 liveDataMerger.addSource(liveData2, value -> liveDataMerger.setValue(value));
```

That's the example from the docs - it's a very simple one that just sets a single value on `liveDataMerger` when *either* of the source LiveDatas posts a new value.

There's [an example on the Android Developers blog](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-beyond-the-viewmodel-reactive-patterns-using-transformations-and-mediatorlivedata-fda520ba00b7) that's closer to what you want:

```
    ...
    result.addSource(liveData1) { value ->
        result.value = combineLatestData(liveData1, liveData2)
    }
    result.addSource(liveData2) { value ->
        result.value = combineLatestData(liveData1, liveData2)
    }
    ...

private fun combineLatestData(
        onlineTimeResult: LiveData<Long>,
        checkinsResult: LiveData<CheckinsResult>
): UserDataResult {

    val onlineTime = onlineTimeResult.value
    val checkins = checkinsResult.value

    // Don't send a success until we have both results
    if (onlineTime == null || checkins == null) {
        return UserDataLoading()
    }

    // TODO: Check for errors and return UserDataError if any.

    return UserDataSuccess(timeOnline = onlineTime, checkins = checkins)
}
```

so every time you get a new value on one of the LiveDatas, you pass them both to a function that does some validation and returns a current state.

I should also point out that `Flow`s [are recommended for a lot of things now](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-livedata-to-kotlins-flow-379292f419fb), and the `combine` function (which does the same kind of thing as `MediatorLiveData`) is a bit easier to read (#5 in that article). Just so you know! Either is good here

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have separate `LiveData` of `DataState` for each API Call.

Rather than this:

```kotlin
val data1 = MutableLiveData<List<model1>>()
val data2 = MutableLiveData<List<model2>>()
```

You can have just this:

```kotlin
private val _stateLiveData = MutableLiveData<DataStates<model3>>()

val statesLiveData: LiveData<DataStates<model3>>
        get() = _stateLiveData
```

Consider `model3` as a `data class` that aggregates both `model1` and `model2`. It can be used to aggregate other data fields that can be used in future.

```kotlin
data class model3(
    var data1: model1?,
    var data2: model2?
)
```

This way, when you observe the states, maintaining states becomes simpler:

```kotlin
viewModel.statesLiveData.observe(this) { states ->
    when(states) {
        is DataStates.Error -> // Handle Error here.
        DataStates.Loading -> // Handle Loading here.
        is DataStates.Success -> // Handle Success here.
    }
}
```

One more thing, since the methods `getData1()` and `getData2()` are launching Coroutines separately, the REST API Calls are not in sequence of one another. And it's not guaranteed which call would finish first, that can lead to extra code just to maintain the progress until both are completed.
This can be solved easily by sequencing the REST API Calls itself, by merging the data fetch operation into one method under one `CoroutineScope`.

To summarize:

```kotlin
class YourViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _stateLiveData = MutableLiveData<DataStates<model3>>()

    val statesLiveData: LiveData<DataStates<model3>>
        get() = _stateLiveData

    init {
        getData()
    }

    private fun getData() {

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

            notifyState(DataStates.Loading)

            try {

                val result1 = repository.getData1().data!!
                val result2 = repository.getData2().data!!

                notifyState(
                    DataStates.Success(
                        model3(
                            result1,
                            result2
                        )
                    )
                )

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                notifyState(DataStates.Error(e))
            }

        }

    }

    private fun notifyState(state: DataStates<model3>) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            _stateLiveData.value = state
        }
    }

}
```